# how to generate <a name=""> using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a way to generate following html without `href` by `link_to` ?

```
 <a name="foobar>header</a>
```

for example:

```
<%= link_to 'header' , nil, :name =>'foobar' %>
```

will generate:

```
<a href='' name='foobar'>header</a>
```

but I want a no `href=''` version.

Comment: Can't you just emit that raw HTML?

Comment: `link_to` creates a link **to** somewhere, not a place a link can point. `<a name>` should be avoided anyway. `<any-element id>` is more flexible. You can link to blocks (instead of just inline content) and you don't have to add an additional element.

Comment: what is `<any-element id>` ? thanks.

Comment: `<div id="foo">…</div>` or `<h3 id="bar">…</h3>` or `<section id="baz">…</section>` etc.

Comment: I even don't know this can work. After try, it just works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't use link_to, but it will accomplish what you're looking to do:

```
<%= content_tag :a, "header", :name => "foobar" %>
```